# $g(x) = sup_{α∈A} (f_α(x))$, $x ∈ E$ need not be a measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $E$, then $g = sup_n f_n$ defined as
$g(x) = sup f_n(x)$, $x ∈ E_ n$
is a measurable function.
Prove by an example that if $A$ is an uncountable index set and for each $α ∈ A$, $f_α$ is a measurable function on $E$, then $g = sup_{α∈A} f_α$ defined as
$g(x) = sup_{α∈A} (f_α(x))$, $x ∈ E$ need not be a measurable function.

Comment: Think to the Vitali set and its characteristic function…

Answer (score 2):

Consider a Vitali set $A \subset [0,1]$, which is non measurable. The aim is to find measurable functions $f_a$ for each $a \in A$, such that $\sup\limits_{a \in A} f_a = \mathbb 1_A$.

Hint :

> $f_a = \Bbb 1_{\{a\}}$